# Why does an input iterator invalidate itself after incrementing?

Tags: c++

I've read that input iterators are used to read in input streams like `cin`, which can contain something like `"abc"`. If we have two iterators, let's say of type`std::istream_iterator` that both point to `'a'`, and we increment one of them, the other one will become invalidated.

I'm wondering why that's the case. It seems like incrementing one iterator would cause it to read in `'b'`, but I'm not sure why incrementing the other one wouldn't allow that to work either. I've read that this does happen, but I'm a little confused as to why it's the case. Is it how the input streams are structured, or something else?

Comment: Clarify please. You're referring to standing up *two* `std::istream_iterator` instances against the same `std::basic_istream&`, correct? I find it odd that wherever you "read that" didn't delve into detail as to *why* it is the case.

Comment: Note that saying that an iterator becomes invalid does not **require** that it not be usable. It **allows** it to not be usable.

Comment: `cin` is a good example... if you read `'a'` then you can't read the same character again, it's not necessarily stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`InputIterator` is not a specific class, it is a concept, which allows efficient implementation of certain constructs. For example, suppose you have a file with lines, max line length is 128 bytes, and you have to provide an iterable interface: with the input iterator concept, you can simply allocate a buffer for a single line, and simply read the next line into this buffer, whenever an input iterator is incremented.

An other example: suppose you have a generator function, which produces the fibonacchi sequence. A `BidirectionalIterator` based implementation would need to store the generated number somewhere, while an `InputIterator` based solution can simply ask the generator for the next number, and drop the current one - no additional storage is needed.